# A question from Golan's linear algebra:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

A question from Golan's linear algebra:

Let $A\in M(n,\mathbb R)$ (which denotes the set of all $n\times n$ matrices, for some $n\geq 2$) be symmetric. Does there exist a symmetric matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$?

It asks again whether it is possible to find such a matrix in case $A$ is symmetric and positive definite? How to do this? Any hints to approach them. I am totally clueless

Comment: I cannot imagine that a book would contain such in incomprehnsible phrase. Can you at least cite it correctly?

Comment: I dont get what you are asking @MarcvanLeeuwen

Comment: "i.e the set of all $n×n$ matrices $n≥2$ is symmetric" is either false or nonsense. I'm asking you to just copy faithfully what is written in the book. Probably it is said (in the book) that $A$ is a symmetric matrix, but that is not what is written in the question above.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I assume he meant to write "the set of all $n\times n$ matrices $n\geq 2$ **that are** symmetric".  I understand your frustration, though

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: actually I think it is slightly different yet. I'll edit, and if it is not that, let OP change it to match the book.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen go for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Every symmetric matrix is unitarily diagonalizable by the spectral theorem.  How could you (easily) construct a square root of a diagonal matrix?

If $B^2 = A$, what could the eigenvalues of $B$ be?  If $A$ is symmetric, what do we know about its eigenvalues?

The answer will be no in general, but yes if $A$ is also positive definite.

---

If $A = UDU^*$ where $D$ is diagonal, try
$$
B = U \pmatrix{\sqrt{\lambda_1}\\&\ddots \\ && \sqrt\lambda_n}U^*
$$

Comment: if $A$ is symmetric all eigen values are real

Comment: if $A$ is positive definite all eigen values are positive also eigen values of $B$ are square root of that of $B$

Comment: is it right? @ Omnomnomnom

Comment: how to construct $B$ is not clear

Comment: The correct statement is that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then at least one of $\sqrt \lambda$ and $-\sqrt \lambda$ must be an eigenvalue of $B$, so you had the right idea.